# Laravel Blade - check if data array has specific key

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I need to check if the data array has a specific key, I tried it like this:

```
@if ( ! empty($data['currentOffset']) )
    <p>Current Offset: {{ $currentOffset }} </p>
@else
    <p>The key `currentOffset` is not in the data array</p>
@endif
```

But I always get `<p>The key`currentOffset`is not in the data array</p>`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use [`@isset`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#control-structures):

```
@isset($data['currentOffset'])
    {{-- currentOffset exists --}}
@endisset
```

Comment: is there also something like `elseisset`? I need an else branch.

Comment: @Black no. If you need `else`, you could just use `@if (isset($data['currentOffset']))` or the ternary operator `{{ isset($data['currentOffset']) ? 'Exists' : 'Doesn\'t exist' }}`

Answer (score 5):

I think you need something like this:

```
 @if ( isset($data[$currentOffset]) )
 ...
```

Comment: Thats exactly what @Alexey Mezenin posted 4 min ago.

Comment: no there is difference between `$data[$currentOffset]` and `$data['currentOffset']`, I think maybe the key was stored in a variable $currentOffset

Answer (score 4):

Use following:

```
@if (array_key_exists('currentOffset', $data))
    <p>Current Offset: {{ $data['currentOffset'] }} </p>
@else
    <p>The key `currentOffset` is not in the data array</p>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

ternary

```
 @php ($currentOffset = isset($data['currentOffset']) ? $data['currentOffset'] : '')
```